# Postgres Query Total login per user a day per database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to write a query that gives me total logins per user, per day and group by user_ID

I have an events.action table that show logins, created_at TIMESTAMP

Any suggestions

I tried to do a subquery count  and I found this query on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't get it work in my favor.

```
select
  userid,
  count(distinct date_trunc('day', datetime)) as countLogins
from
 events
where
  action = 'login'
Group by
  userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this depending on your database structure:

SELECT
user_id,
DATE(created_at) AS date,
COUNT(*) as countLogins
FROM
events
WHERE
action = 'login'
GROUP BY
user_id,
DATE(created_at);

Comment: Thank you shippi, I think this may work.  I appreciate your help.